im trying to call the method i made in function.php but undefined. i write it correctly though. still gets the fatal error, help me this is my 1st php

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
is_admin_login() in D:\xamapp\htdocs\LMS\header.php:47 Stack trace: #0
D:\xamapp\htdocs\LMS\index.php(5): include() #1 {main} thrown in
D:\xamapp\htdocs\LMS\header.php on line 47

this is the function.php

This is my other index.php in another folder(admin)


 
header.php declaring the method is_admin_login.
<?php 

if(is_admin_login())
{

?>
<body class="sb-nav-fixed">

    <nav class="sb-topnav navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <!-- Navbar Brand-->
        <a class="navbar-brand ps-3" href="index.php">Library System</a>
        <!-- Sidebar Toggle-->
        <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm order-1 order-lg-0 me-4 me-lg-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#!"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
        <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ms-auto me-0 me-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
            
        </form>
        <!-- Navbar-->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ms-md-0 me-3 me-lg-4">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="setting.php">Setting</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="layoutSidenav">
        <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
            <nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-dark" id="sidenavAccordion">
                <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
                    <div class="nav">
    
                        <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sb-sidenav-footer">
                   
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
            <main>


<?php 
}
else
{
?>

<body>

    <main>

        <div class="container py-4">

            <header class="pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="index.php" class="d-flex align-items-center text-dark text-decoration-none">
                            <span class="fs-4">Library Management System</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </header>
<?php 
}
?>


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Code, data and logs are text. Provide it as text, please. See also [ask] where this is mentioned. Images of text are not searchable, copyable, or re-usable in answers, examples, research etc. This makes it a lot harder for people to help you by re-using the data in a test scenario or an answer, and for others with similar issues to find your question. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

Where did you include function.php into header.php? You haven't shown that. That would be the obvious reason for it failing. You've only included header.php into index.php. If you want to use code from function.php, you have to include that file as well.

but sir admin, if i include function.php to header.php the error will say Fatal error: Cannot redeclare is_admin_login() (previously declared in D:\xamapp\htdocs\LMS\function.php:7) in D:\xamapp\htdocs\LMS\function.php on line 5

So it's not clear - you say This is my other index.php... do you mean this is a different page than the one which has the problem? You have two index.php pages. Which one has the error? You have made it ambiguous. I can't see how the one you've shown us could be producing the error message.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare is_admin_login()...presumably because whatever you've changed is causing function.php to be included twice. You shouldn't do that.

"This is my other index.php in another folder(admin)" - not the index.php that is triggering this, according to the error message. Stack trace: #0 D:\xamapp\htdocs\LMS\index.php(5): include() #1 says that this happened while you called your index.php in the root folder, not the one in the admin subfolder.

Seems that you forgot to include your 'function.php' file to your index.php or even the header.php.
Try it and check if you'r file is included:
$included_files = get_included_files();
print_r($included_files);

